# bash syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator

Tags: bash

I have this bash code, when I run this, it throws `arithmetic operator error`

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$1;
cluster=`cd $1; df -k . | tail -1 | awk -F: '{print $1}' | awk -F- '{print $1}'`
volume=`cd $1; df -k . | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk -F/ '{print $3}'`

if [[ $cluster == *"clap"* ]]; then
avg_latency_val=$(cd /net/kkcmon02/app/whisper/netapp/perf/sanjose/$cluster-cls-mgt/svm/vs0/vol/$volume; whisper-fetch --pretty avg_latency.wsp| tail -n 30 | grep -v None | awk -v N=6 '{ sum += $N } END { if ( NR > 0 ) {print sum/NR} else {print 0}}')

elif [[ $cluster == *"isic"* ]]; then
echo "Graphana can monitor only Netapp volumes & this is a volume coming from Isilon."

else
avg_latency_val=$(cd /net/kkcmon02/app/whisper/netapp/perf7/sanjose/$cluster/vol/$volume; whisper-fetch --pretty avg_latency.wsp| tail -n 30 | grep -v None | awk -v N=6 '{ sum += $N } END { if ( NR > 0 ) {print sum/NR} else {print 0}}')

fi

if [[ "${avg_latency_val}" -le  "30" ]] ; then
    echo "Average Latency on the volume for last 30 mins is "${avg_latency_val}" ms (Good)"

elif [[ "${avg_latency_val}" -gt "30" ]] ; then
    echo "Average Latency on the volume for last 30 mins is "${avg_latency_val}" ms (Bad)"

else
    echo "Average Latency on the volume Looks Good!!"
fi
```

Below is the error occurred when I ran the above code. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here

> k_test.sh: line 21: [[: 1.98381: syntax error: invalid arithmetic
>   operator (error token is ".98381")

Comment: You've got a lot going on here. Can you post just the part you're having trouble with?

Comment: If it's a problem with decimals, try using the `bc` command

Comment: If you're trying to do arithmetic use `((..))` instead of `[[..]]`

Answer (score -3):

Bash only handles integer numbers. You will have to do some chop shop work to get it to understand a decimal point like that

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: What do you mean "chop shop work?" `bc` handles decimals just fine. `bc -q <<< "scale=9; (3.38524*(-2.3423))"`

Comment: elif [[ "${avg_latency_val}" -gt "30" ]] ;
It can't tell if this value is greater than because its a decimal point... 

Workaround: Remove the decimal point and simply change it to a different measurement of time.

If you took the time to read, it attualy tells you...
invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".98381")

Maybe read before giving me attitude...

Comment: @JonathanPugh, will try that.

Comment: I don't think that anyone is "giving you attitude", the point is that a vague reference to "chop shop work" is not a helpful answer.

Comment: and "How is this an answer" is ?
Bash doesn't deal with decimals... Find a way to not use decimals. Was kind of implied

Comment: No, it's a comment.

Comment: Comment with attitude...

Comment: @JonathanPugh, thnaks for your hints and inputs, i sorted it out avoiding decimals which are causing issues.

Comment: -1. While this is an accurate statement, this does not answer the OPs question. For example, you could have included an example of a different way to do floating-point math in a Bash script. Example programs that can do this include `bc` and `calc`.